# If an event is unbined , can't we restore it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making the twitter follow button , when you click on it it turns to following, when hover again it turns to unfollow , when click on unfollow , it becomes follow and here even if the mouse goes out nothing happens , my problem is something happens here .. (last step)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 menu followBlock">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-follow="follow">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  Follow
    </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".followBlock").on('click', "button[data-follow=follow]", function(e) {
    $btn = $(this);
            $btn.html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Following").removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
            $("button[data-follow=follow]").attr("data-follow", "unfollow");
            $btn.hover(function(e) {
                $(this).html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span> Unfollow").removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
            }, function(e) {
                $(this).html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> Following").removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
            })


});
$(".followBlock").on('click', "button[data-follow=unfollow]", function(e) {
    $btn = $(this);
            $btn.html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Follow").removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary');


});
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ5nn/1/) that explains my problem: 
jsfiddle.net/TQ5nn/1/

Help please

Comment: You can't (easily) rebind anonymous functions. Move the handler into a function of its own, and then use `.on('click', funcName)` and `.off('click', funcName)`.

Comment: did you even take a look on the jsfiddle ?

Comment: You will want to deal with states and toggling CSS classes instead.

Comment: Who, me? Yes I did...

Comment: LOL , What's wrong with you people ? can you at least take time to read and UNDERSTAND the code ? 
I don't want the hover event to run when clicking unfollow , but I want it when I click Follow !

Comment: @Sekai What's wrong with us? Read my first comment, the answer you're looking for is in there...

Comment: lol youre binding two click events on the same button and never unbind anything and additionally you bind a hover that only works for the following state

Comment: Exactly ! I tried that , but once I off the event , It can't be turned on again , that's my problem !

Comment: @johnSmith if you look closely , it's not the same button it's data-follow that changes

Comment: @Sekai did you try my suggestion, rather than complaining?

Comment: @Sekai check out my answer ... you don't change the `data-follow` back to follow on the second click event ...

Comment: Catalin ! Thank you very much that was it  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(".followBlock").on('click', "button[data-follow=unfollow]", function(e) {
    $btn = $(this);
    $btn.html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Follow").removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-primary');
    $btn.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $btn.attr('data-follow', 'follow');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ5nn/2/)

Comment: Thank you dear sir ! Instead of commenting you went right to the solution !